# Dynamic and not dynamic data in the same Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google

I am taking a range of names from another tab with the formula
`=SORT(UNIQUE('brands check'!B9:B8228))` in column B.
I would like to add descriptions in other columns (D, E, etc.), but as soon as I add a new name in the 'brands check' file the list is changing, and the descriptions are not matching anymore the original name.

Is there a way to keep the description attached to the shifting name?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to insert the other columns like this (note the curly brackets):

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({
'brands check'!B9:B,
'brands check'!C9:C,
'brands check'!D9:D
}))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
The columns where I want to add the description are entered manually and not from the other tab (brands check).

Comment: The description of an element must be made in the same table as the element, any other position would be conceptually wrong.